# JTA Datasource java configuration in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss, datasource

So for the last few days I've been trying to configure a JTA datasource with spring, however no matter hpw much I google I can't find out how to do this.

This is the current datasource config I have, but this is for a local datasource config

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/expenses");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

This is the configuration of my datasource in my standalone.xml of my jboss 8 :

```
 <datasource jndi-name="java:/ExpensesDataSource" pool-name="ExpensesDataSourcePool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/expenses</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

Obviously now I have double code since I'm not evening use the datasource from my jboss. I want to configure my jta datasource to use this datasource using jndi lookup.

EDIT#2:

So eventually I found this piece of code:

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup jndiDataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return jndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:/ExpensesDataSource");
    }
```

However this gives me the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:/ExpensesDataSource'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

EDIT#2:

I've looked around a bit and found out I need to set some initial environment params, got to this:

```
Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
        jndiProperties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
        jndiProperties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        jndiProperties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming.org.jnp.interfaces");
        JndiDataSourceLookup jndiDataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        jndiDataSourceLookup.setJndiEnvironment(jndiProperties);
        return jndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:global/ExpensesDataSource");
```

I tried `localhost`, `localhost:1099` and `http://localhost:1099` as `Context.PROVIDER_URL`, none of them work includng this one. Giving me the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:274)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1533)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:248)
    ... 97 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:328)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:84)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:77)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:244)
    ... 97 more
```

Comment: you can check this answer if it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197236/spring-jndi-configuration-problem

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help me

Comment: I added a new more specific question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123737/configuring-a-jta-datasource-for-jboss-8-wildfly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that in JBOSS 8 you have the following namespaces

- java:comp
- java:module
- java:app
- java:global
- java:jboss
- java:/

So in your spring application put

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="datasource" jndi-name="java:global/ExpensesDataSource"></jee:jndi-lookup>
```

or

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup jndiDataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    return jndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:global/ExpensesDataSource");
}
```

And in your standalone.xml configuration try to follow this [snippet](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JNDI+Reference)

Comment: Hey I read the docs and I dont think I have to do any additional configuration in my jboss

Comment: Maybe not. You should see the name in your lookup. How I said you have 6 forms to refer a JNDI Name how specified above.

Comment: The name in my lookup is java:/ExpensesDataSource

Comment: You are doing java:/ExpensesDataSource. Try java:global/ExpensesDataSource

Comment: I believe that you're using java config so, you should change in your spring configuration in dataSource() method.

Comment: Aye I meant xml config in jboss-standalone.xml :p