# Configuring a JTA datasource for JBoss 8 (WildFly)

Tags: java, jboss, datasource, jndi

So, I read several times that if you use a Java EE container, you do not need to add environment params to an  `InitialContext` in order to be able to use JNDI.

So I tried this:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup jndiDataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return jndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:global/ExpensesDataSource");
    }
```

However, retrieving a datasource using JNDI like this gives me a `NoInitialContextException`, telling me to specify the environment params.

Now, okay, so seems I was wrong to think it would work so flawlessly, so I tried retrieving the datasource like this:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
        jndiProperties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
        jndiProperties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        jndiProperties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming.org.jnp.interfaces");
        JndiDataSourceLookup jndiDataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        jndiDataSourceLookup.setJndiEnvironment(jndiProperties);
        return jndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:global/ExpensesDataSource");
    }
```

However this gives me a `javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099`

I've also tried just using `localhost:1099` or `localhost`, none of them worked.

So my question is: do I even need to specify these properties, since JBoss 8 is a Java EE container to my knowledge. And if so, what provider url do I need to specify here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use javax.naming.InitialContext, you don't need to specify environment params, just like you said. For example:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS");
```

Not sure how JndiDataSourceLookup works..

For looking up a datasource, you can inject it using @Resource (inside an ejb context)

```
@Resource(name= "java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS")
private Datasource ds;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've tried this before, however this gives me an javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file: .... exception. My code is from a Spring configuration file